# Can I combine Brownie to view events and contracts on Ganache?

Tags: truffle, events, ganache, smart-contract-wallets, brownie

It seems that ganache can only work for truffle-config file , if i want to see the events and smart contracts on my local ganache blockchain?

I am developing an app where i want to locally test the flow. But it seems ganache can only support truffle projects?

So i am having to rely on deploying to test net to test instead (quite annoying because I have to keep using and finding test eth faucets)

Any solutions? Thanks!